# How to implement fconnect(Facebook) for like page in Android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a scenario in which when user will click on fconnect(Facebook) button then FB login and password page will open, user will enter his/her credential then specific FB like page will open there user will like or dislike FB page after doing this control will automatically go to another activity class on which user will perform some task and then user will logout from Facebook by clicking on logout button.

Please, tell how I will implement this scenario through Android.
Please provide me any tutorial or blog or sample code thanks in Advance.

Comment: hi faiz i have the same problem.